# Multiple calls to a portlet method in Renderer class

Tags: plone, portlet

I'm creating a portlet based on Base Portlet.

In the Renderer class, I've defined a method like this :

```py
def myMethod(self):
    """ """
    logger.info("hou yeah")
    ....
```

In  the portlet's template I call `view/myMethod`

In the root site, I add my portlet.

- When I go to http://www.example.com/ I see `hou yeah` one time. Great.
- When I go to http://www.example.com/folder1 I see `hou yeah` twice. Uh ?
- When I go to http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3 I see `hou yeah` four time. Really ?

Etc...

Is this a normal behavior ?

Is there a way to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Showing some code always helps ;)

Comment: Have you tried putting in a `pdb.set_trace()` and looking at the stack every time your method is hit? Type `w` to see the call stack to see what is calling your method every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour, I think. you've just to find which transaction was the right one. The others are deleted by zope transactions handling.

Comment: this is not correct.. what has this got to do with transactions?

Comment: This has been my experience in similar methods.

Comment: Think you misunderstand transactions. The idea is the changes to the Database will get committed at the end of the request if it succeeds - otherwise nothing will be committed to the database and the ZODB will be left in the same state as the beginning of the request. Methods will not be called multiple times.